# How to show hero card in from bot in xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, botframework, direct-line-botframework, adaptive-cards

Using direct channel with adaptive card rendering for xamarin and it works fine. When I start using the other types of cards like hero card from bot it's not rendering in xamarin app. Do I need to create a custom control for it or does bot client has any integration for rendering such cards in xamarin?

Comment: Are you using this library: https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/tree/master/source/dotnet ?

Comment: Using : https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/tree/master/source/dotnet

Comment: yes that is the one

Comment: created an issue in the github , https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3271

Answer (score 1):

Figured that there is a method called "Prompter" for formflow and we can use it for sending the adapativecard instead of herocard.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1102

Comment: Thanks Sowmyan!  I wasn't aware of this option.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin Adaptive Cards library is for Adaptive Cards, and doesn't have renders for Bot Framework SDK card types.  You would need to translate the BotFramework card type into an Adaptive Card to make it work with that library's renderer.  Or, write a renderer.

Comment: Thanks, if I use default form flow how can handle the attachment to go as adaptive card type ? If there is no way then the only solution is custom renderer

Comment: It should be relatively straight forward to transform the HeroCard or ThumbnailCard payload into an adaptive card object model, and then use the xamarin forms renderer the adaptive card model. (Note that the X.Forms renderer is a pretty early right now while we finish the native renderers.)